# Category Filter Block duplicates itself when resizing from responsive to normal view RWD theme

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd

I am having a problem when re-sizing a page from normal size to responsive size, the category filter block will duplicate itself and cause visual bugs with the page. Here is an image of what it looks like:

[image: filter duplicating]

I have looked in left.phtml, and that is the block that seems to be called over and over that is causing the problem. The offending code looks like it comes from app.js. Has anyone dealt with anything like this before and have a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Javascript error. I simply copied over app.js from another installation and the problem was resolved

Answer (score 1):

Had this same problem. Rwd's app.js moves the left sidebar above `.category-products` on small screens and back to left on larger screens. However, that class exists on the `<body>` tag as well. So when resizing your screen, that block is being duplicated.

My solution.

app.js around line 930
From this -

```
  $j('.col-left-first').insertBefore($j('.category-products'))
```

To this -

```
  $j('.col-left-first').insertBefore($j('.category-products').not('body.category-products'))
```

Worked for me.